# Child component broken CSS style

Tags: vuejs3

I have a Vue child component, nothing special in this component, just separating code. However the Bootstrap style seems to be broken if I add Text Interpolation. Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr>
                <td>No.</td>
                <td>Pertanyaan/Persyaratan/Kriteria</td>
                <td colspan="3">Kelengkapan </td>
                <td>Komentar/Catatan</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tidak </td>
                <td>Ya</td>
                <td>NA</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6">Umum</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>i</td>
                <td>Konsistensi antara dokumen tercetak dengan soft copy</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check text-center">
                        <input class="form-check-input float-none" type="radio" name="umum_i">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check text-center">
                        <input class="form-check-input float-none" type="radio" name="umum_i">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check text-center">
                        <input class="form-check-input float-none" type="radio" name="umum_i">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="">
                        <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
                        {{ audit01_umum_i }}
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                audit01_umum_i: ''
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Notice there is a property named `audit01_umum_i`. I render this prop in template section using text interpolation, and the problem start showing, see this image:

[image: with text interpolation]

but if I remove the text interpolation, everything is good:

[image: without text interpolation]

What could be the problem?

PS: another weird issue is, if I unwrap the `table` (it's now wrapped using `div`), the template is also become broken.

Comment: Would you replicate your issue on Codepen and share the link with us? This would greatly assist us in understanding and resolving your issue more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Using `<thead></thead>` and `<tbody></tbody>` to wrap `<tr></tr>` will fix this problem.